# How to validate the Jquery UI- Calendar plugin?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have used JqueryUI plugin- date picker to display my date.
The format is such that it has Fromdate & Todate. 
If I select fromDate: for example 09/28/2010 and
If I select toDate:   for example 09/30/2010. It should be like this such that todate is
always the one which comes after the fromdate.

But i want to validate such that if I click toDate that is from previous month 
or the day before fromDate the validation should not allow me to select a date which is 
previous that of fromDate.

My Jscript is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fromDate').datepicker({clickInput:true});
            $('.toDate').datepicker({clickInput:true});
});
    </script>
```

My html is

```
 <tr><td>Enter FromDate:</td><td><input type="text" id="fromDate" class="fromDate"
 readonly /></td></tr>
```

Enter ToDate:

**How to do that. Any suggestions Please.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom validation method for jQuery Validate for that. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/end-date-greater-than-start-date-jquery-validation/848548#848548) here on SO.