# How can I write a javascript code that uses set time to make a statement?

Tags: javascript, html

Im working on a website, and between the hours of 9:00 and 24:00, the business is open. During those hours, i want a line of text to say "Store is currently open" but during 0:00 - 8:59, i want the line of text to say "Store is closed".

Comment: Between 0900 and 2400 where? Where you are? Where your server is? Where your customer is? All of the above? None of the above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing Time using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406505/comparing-time-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/). If you're only targetting local users you don't even have to worry about time-zone differences. Otherwise you can always specify a timezone to use, simply see [the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

```js
var now = moment();
var status = (now.isAfter(moment('09:00', 'hh:mm')) && now.isBefore(moment('21:00', 'hh:mm'))) ? 'open' : 'closed';

var d = document.createElement("span");
d.appendChild(document.createTextNode("the time is now " + moment().format('hh:mm') + ". pool's " + status + "."));
document.body.appendChild(d);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```