# Jquery form validator - how can one check that a date is past a date in another field?

Tags: jquery, forms, date, conditional-statements, validation

I'm building a form in which I have a start date and an end date field.
I'm planning on using jQuery UI datepicker and jquery validationEngine scripts.
The problem I have, besides from being a beginner in jQuery, is that I'm not sure how to prevent the user from entering an end date that is before the start date.

The validation engine I'm using is:
http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate that end date is greater than start date with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/validate-that-end-date-is-greater-than-start-date-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/end-date-greater-than-start-date-jquery-validation) in regard to same question

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure this is the same validation engine. I'm using this one: http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/ and I don't seem to recognize the syntax in the other question you referred me to...

Comment: @Argo the one is the thread use http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ which i think is what most people use it was made by one of the jQuery developers, you may want to add what validator you are using to your post if you want to continue using that validator. generally speaking its best to put as much detail in your post as you can

Comment: you're absolutely right. I've added the URL to the post. I'd rather like to keep this one, unless what I'm trying to do here proves impossible.

Comment: @@Argo did this lead you to the answer you needed ?