# How do I validate that the end date is greater than start date?

Tags: jquery, validation, date

I used [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/end-date-greater-than-start-date-jquery-validation) to solve my problem.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", function(value, element, params) {
    return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
}, 'Must be greater than {0}.');
```

However, my date field is a textbox and formatted like `dd-mm-yyyy`. How do I change this code so that the validation works?

Answer (score 0):

You will first have to parse your textbox value to get date from it. Best way would be regular expressions:

Your validator function body should be (explanations in inline comments):

```
// date parsing regular expression
var rx = /([0-2]?\d|3[01])-(0?\d|1[0-2])-(\d{4})/i;

// get textbox value
var val = $(params).val();

// default date
var date = new Date();

// parse date if entered correctly
if (rx.test(val))
{
    // get date parts
    var result = rx.exec(val);

    // generate date instance
    date = new Date(result[3], result[2]-1, result[1]);
}

// validate dates
return new Date(value) > date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ValidateEndDate() {
        var startDate = $("txtfromdate").val();
        var endDate = $("txttodate").val();
        if (startDate != '' && endDate !='') {
            if (Date.parse(startDate) > Date.parse(endDate)) {
                $("txttodate").val('');
                alert("Start date should not be greater than end date");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```