# how can I set a max value on my html5 date input so that it could be recognized by safari for iOS?

Tags: ios, html, date, input, datepicker

The title is pretty clear I guess?

Here's my date input :

```
<input type="date" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" value="" max="1993-12-07" required/>
```

In chrome, I cannot enter a date superior to 1993-12-07 using the little arrows of the field (but if I write the date myself I can).

In safari for iOS, focusing that field just brings a nice datepicker. However, this datepicker is NOT limited to the "max" attribute. So how can I do that? Of course, I have a server-side form validation but I want to make it on client-side too. 
Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Safari does not yet support it yet . Only Opera and chrome support it as of Nov 2011. Anyways here is the w3spec on it http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.max

You can use js validation on submit or on change. Use a js validation framework of your choice

Here is pure js example http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Ajax/4734-start-date-and-end-date-validation-in-javascript.html. Use your max date instead of end date

For jquery solution look at this [Validate that end date is greater than start date with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/end-date-greater-than-start-date-jquery-validation)

Comment: Now, at October 2014 - mobile Safari support max and min at date?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich any link to support

Comment: I don't know any link - it is was question.

Comment: Even in November 2016, mobile Safari does not support max and min attributes of date.

Comment: Even in January 2020, mobile Safari still does not support max and min attributes of date (iOS 13.0)

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution for dynamically disabling future dates:

```
@{ string datestring = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); }
<input type="date" 
       required="required" 
       name="AttendanceDate" 
       max="@datestring" 
       class="form-control" />
```

Comment: This works fine on Android, but on iOS the min and max properties aren't taken in account