# HTML5 on iPad - input type date

Tags: ipad, html, date

I'm writing a WEB app in HTML5(actually it's PHP) for iPad.

I added a date input like

```
<input type="date" id="start" name="start" min="2012-10-04" max="2012-11-05">
```

When I tap on this, the date picker appears, but min value and max value seem to be ignored. I can choose any date I want even it's out of min/max dates.

How can I limit date picker's range as I want?

I include "modernizr-2.5.3-respond-1.1.0.min.js" in header. Those two conflict?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I set a max value on my html5 date input so that it could be recognized by safari for iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417199/how-can-i-set-a-max-value-on-my-html5-date-input-so-that-it-could-be-recognized)