# Cordova/Phonegap iOS date picker - limit to past only

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Is there an easy way to limit the date to today's date and older using native date picker through `<input type="date/>` on iOS?

Comment: Can't you use the min and max attributes?

Comment: no, they don't seem to work.

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417199/how-can-i-set-a-max-value-on-my-html5-date-input-so-that-it-could-be-recognized) It looks like safari doesn't support it yet.

Comment: Here is a workaround for Cordova. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943511/limit-the-selectable-dates-in-native-datepicker-in-ios-phonegap-app/26086166#26086166