# Compare Dates using validate.js

Tags: jquery, datetime

in jquery i try to validate my page.I have to filds `txtStartDate` and `txtEndDate`.i want to validate start date is lower than end date.How this condition append in given code.Bcz `txtPageName` and `txtTitle` is already validate.Thanks.

```
                 var v = $("#form1").validate({
                    ignore: ':hidden',
                    rules: {
                        : { required: true },
                        txtTitle: { required: true }


                    },
                    messages: {
                        txtPageName: "<br/>Please enter a Page Name",
                        txtTitle: "<br/>Please enter a Title"
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/end-date-greater-than-start-date-jquery-validation

Comment: @SKS thanks for link.But as above link i try and got a error in console `jQuery.validate is undefined`.Any way thanks for a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can need a custom rule for doing this. See the below code:
**isAfterStartDate** checks is start date if less than end date and returns a boolean. This is used by the custom validation rule to validate the txtEndDate.

```
var isAfterStartDate = function(startDateStr, endDateStr) {
            var inDate = new Date(startDateStr),
                eDate = new Date(endDateStr);

            if(inDate < eDate) {
                return false;
            }

        };
jQuery.validator.addMethod("isAfterStartDate", function(value, element) {

        return isAfterStartDate($('#txtStartDate').val(), value);
    }, "End date should be after start date");

 var v = $("#form1").validate({
                ignore: ':hidden',
                rules: {
                    txtPageName: { required: true },
                    txtTitle: { required: true },
                    txtStartDate : {required: true}
                    txtEndDate: {
                                  required: true,
                                  isAfterStartDate: true
                                 }


                },
                messages: {
                    txtPageName: "<br/>Please enter a Page Name",
                    txtTitle: "<br/>Please enter a Title"
                }
            });
```

This works assuming the date is format "dd/mm/yyyy".

Comment: Thanks a lot.But i Got a error `jQuery.validator is undefined`.what is my mistake?

Comment: Just asking, have you included jQuery validation plugin in your page?

Comment: Ya i include jQuery validation plugin.