# End date greater than start date with mm/yyyy ? jquery validator

Tags: jquery, validation, date, split

i saw this example : [Validate that end date is greater than start date with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/end-date-greater-than-start-date-jquery-validation)

talking about the validation of end date greater than start, date format for my input are always mm/yyyy, so it's not working for me if :
start date > 122000
end date > 012002

I think i have to split my date, to just check on yyyy, if is greater or not, but didn't know how to resolve it ... here is my code ( i want always to say that if i have not 7 characters in my input to don't pass form submit  :

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="starddate" />
<input type="text" id="enddate" />
<div id="msg"></div>
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
```

JS

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", 
function(value, element, params) {

    if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
        return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
    }

    return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val()) 
        || (parseFloat(value) > parseFloat($(params).val())); 
},'Must be greater than {0}.');

$("#enddate").rules('add', { greaterThan: "#startdate" });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your date values are strings are in the form `mm/yyyy`, then you can't use `new Date(value)` to create a `Date` object for them — that's not a format that the `Date` constructor [is documented as accepting](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.3.2) (and until recently, it wasn't documented to accept anything at all except whatever the output of `toString` was, which was also up to the implementation to decide).

But the problem's not difficult: Given dateA and dateB which are strings in that format:

```
// Assumes the format mm/yyyy (not mmyyyy, which your example values seem to be in)
var compareA, compareB;
compareA = dateA.substring(3) + dateA.substring(0, 2);
compareB = dateB.substring(3) + dateB.substring(0, 2);
if (compareA > compareB) {
    // The date represented by `dateA` is later than the date
    // represented by `dateB`
}
```

or less clearly

```
if (dateA.substring(3) + dateA.substring(0, 2) > dateB.substring(3) + dateB.substring(0, 2)) {
    // ...
}
```

E.g., you can just compare strings if you move the year before the month, because the string `"200012"` is `<` the string `"200201"`.