# Bootstrap Datepicker: Ensuring EndDate > StartDate as well as having a max start date

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Apologies if my title is on the crappy side.  I should also start by mentioning that this is an MVC application if that matters.

Here's what I'm trying to do.  I want my datepickers to have the following requirements:

- The start date must have a range of today - 45 days ago
- The end date must not be able to go past today
- The end date must come after the start date

Here is what I've tried so far and have gotten the first 2 bullets working:

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6 row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="StartDate">Start Date</label>
      <input  type="text" id="StartDate" class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-start-date="-45d" data-date-end-date="0d">
      <label for="EndDate">End Date </label>
      <input  type="text" id="EndDate" class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-start-date="-45d" data-date-end-date="0d">
      </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#StartDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    onSelect: function (selected) {
      $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
    }
  });
  $("#EndDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    onSelect: function (selected) {
      $("#StartDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
    }
  });
```

I've tried also removing some of the data attributes in the HTML and instead adding them to the datepicker methods in the javascript to no avail.

I tried using the solutions to these following questions as well to no avail:

- [how to compare two datepicker date jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169772/how-to-compare-two-datepicker-date-jquery)
- [Twitter Bootstrap datepicker: how to enable only specific daterange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652492/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-how-to-enable-only-specific-daterange?lq=1)

**It also appears that most of the examples I've found use JQuery UI 1.9.2.  I only use JQuery 1.9.1 and NOT UI.  Does that make a difference?**

I'm new to javascript and all this other web stuff so I'm sure I'm missing something very simple but any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well okay it looks like I found my own answer.

Turns out I was using a combination of two different plug-ins.. Oops.  So in case anyone else has a problem with validating start date < end date at all times as well as restricting initial start and end dates, here is what I was able to get working.

```
$("#StartDate").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
  }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('#EndDate').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
  });

  $("#EndDate").datepicker({
    autoclose: true
  }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('#StartDate').datepicker('setEndDate', minDate);
  });
```