# Django form custom Date validation

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-validation

I have a django class that has two date attributes--a start date, and an end date. I want to make a custom validation requirement that says that the start date HAS to be before the end date (or on the same date). I know this revolves custom validation, but don't really know where this should go (in the model? in the view?, etc.).

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: When you can validate it? on save?

Comment: @lalo I imagine what I want is for the `form.is_valid()` method to return False if I have end_date<start_date

Comment: Show the form definition and the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [Form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

If you want to validate on model save, use [django pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save)

Comment: Yes. That's 100% what I was looking for. I simply subtracted the two dates (creating a timedelta), converted that into total seconds, and checked to see if that was <0. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I would put the validation in both the model and the template.  Yes, that's twice the work in two different languages (Python and Javascript), but you'll get cleaner data this way.  Here's one way to do this in jQuery: [end date greater than start date - jquery validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2241515/584846).

The model is the place to put all data validation for that model.  Create a method that takes all the parameters and raises exceptions (ValueError, etc.) if the data is incorrect.