# Jquery Validation Rules for comparing two numbers

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have these two Input boxes

```
form_open('performances/save/'.$performance_info->prf_id,array('id'=>'performance_form'));

    form_input(array(
            'class'=>'beg_inv',
            'name'=>'beg_inv',
            'id'=>'beg_inv',
            'value'=>$performance_info->beg_inv);

    form_input(array(
            'class'=>'end_inv',
            'name'=>'end_inv',
            'id'=>'end_inv',
            'value'=>$performance_info->end_inv);

form_submit(array(
    'name'=>'submit',
    'id'=>'submit',
    'value'=>$this->lang->line('common_submit'),
    'class'=>'submit_button float_right')
);
```

and i am using this jquery validate:

```
$('#performance_form').validate({

    submitHandler:function(form)
    {
        $('#prf_id').val($('#scan_performance').val());
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        success:function(response)
        {
            tb_remove();
            post_exp_form_submit(response);
        },
        dataType:'json'
    });

    },
    errorLabelContainer: "#error_message_box",
    wrapper: "li",
    rules:
    {
        prod_id:"required",
        beg_inv: { greaterThan: "#end_inv" }


    },
    messages:
    {
        prod_id:"<?php echo $this->lang->line('performances_product'); ?>",
        beg_inv:"<?php echo $this->lang->line('performances_qty_val'); ?>"

    }
});
```

I used the greaterThan as I have seen in this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/end-date-greater-than-start-date-jquery-validation/10298956) but that is for dates only I think because my code above does not work. What is the equivalent of the greaterThan for numbers? Or are there any?

EDIT:

adding this worked out, new question: How do I Validate again when I corrected the end_inv without going back to the beg_inv to trigger the rule. If I add a new rule it will create a new error line instead of overwriting the first error message. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/Xczcx/) by Riley

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "greaterThan",
    function (value, element, params) 
    {
        var target = $(params).val();
        var isValueNumeric = !isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value);
        var isTargetNumeric = !isNaN(parseFloat(target)) && isFinite(target);
        if (isValueNumeric && isTargetNumeric) {
            return Number(value) > Number(target);
        }

        if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
            return new Date(value) > new Date(target);
        }

        return false;
    }, 'Must be greater than {0}.');
```

Comment: That link is supposed to work for numbers as well as dates...

Comment: is there anything I am doing wrong? The "required" works fine for prod_id.

Comment: Seems to work fine to me - http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/Xczcx/

Comment: This is using codeigniter right?

Comment: Now I made it work, but how do I remove the "Red Error Message" when I correct the End Val without going back to the Beg Val to rerun the query?