# How to set date2>date1 in Jquery UI Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Hi i want to select date of birth from first date picker. In second date picker pick dates only above date of birth.

http://jsfiddle.net/boopathirajan/6c3v5gna/2/

I added code here.

so help me how to pick date2>date1 only

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" value="" id="date1" name="dob">
        <input type="text" value="" id="date2" name="vcc">
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
    jQuery('#date1').datepicker({
                              dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
                              maxDate: 0
                              });

   jQuery('#date2').datepicker({
                              dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
                              maxDate: 0
                             });
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/end-date-greater-than-start-date-jquery-validation

Comment: no need to validate dates after selection @Yunus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine

```
jQuery('#date1').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
        maxDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            $('#date2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
               }
            });

jQuery('#date2').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
        maxDate:0,
        minDate:1,
      });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/boopathirajan/6c3v5gna/4/)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution for you.

```
jQuery('#date1').datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(selected) {
          $("#date2").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
     }
});

jQuery('#date2').datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(selected) {
           $("#date1").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
    }
 });
```

[JSFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Yunus_Aslam/j66kostL/)

OR a different Approach

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#date1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (date) {
        var date2 = $('#date1').datepicker('getDate');
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
    }
});
$('#date2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    onClose: function () {
        var dt1 = $('#date1').datepicker('getDate');
        var dt2 = $('#date2').datepicker('getDate');
        //check to prevent a user from entering a date below date of dt1
        if (dt2 <= dt1) {
            var minDate = $('#date2').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
            $('#date2').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i already got it. thanks for your good effort.