# jquery validate: apply custom method if conditionally required

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have three fields in my form: status, ask date, and expected date

If my Status=A, I would like my expected date to be required in validation
additionally I would like my expected date validated to always be greater than the ask date

so here are my rules

```
rules: {
      status: {
        required: true,
      },
      ask_date: {
        required: true,
        date:true,
      },
      expected_date: {

        required: function(element){
            if($('#status').val()=='A'){
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
        },

        greaterThan: "#ask_date",
        date:true,
      },
```

How can I say invoke the greaterThan method ONLY when the field meets the  conditions for being required?

the "greaterThan" is custom jquery validation method i am using for this from a separate stack overflow here [Validate that end date is greater than start date with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/end-date-greater-than-start-date-jquery-validation)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", 
function(value, element, params) {

    if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
        return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
    }

    return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val()) 
        || (Number(value) > Number($(params).val())); 
},'Must be greater than {0}.');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "How can I say invoke the `greaterThan` method ONLY when the field meets the `required` conditions?"

Since the field is only `required` under those conditions, ideally, none of your other rules should be fired when the field is left blank.  However, there is a piece missing from your custom method that would allow it to be ignored whenever the field is left blank.

Testing against the condition, `this.optional(element)`, will ensure that your custom rule is not enforced on a blank field.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", function(value, element, params) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {  // "required" not in force and field is empty
        return true;
    } else {  // otherwise, use your rule
        if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
            return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
        }
        return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val()) || (Number(value) > Number($(params).val()));
    }
},'Must be greater than {0}.');
```

Comment: @whoami, you have enough reputation to already know that we are not allowed to ask/answer questions from within comments.