# PHP Validation of start date and end date using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I am trying to use `JavaScript/JQuery` to implement a function in which it would detect read the selected date within a form and perform the following `validation`:

> 1) Start date can't be before the current date
>
> 2) End date can't be before the start date / start date can't be after
>   the end date
>   If it occurs, the error message would be displayed in my `#ErrorBox`

Below is the code I have done as of now, it ensures the user to enter their goal, start date, end date and description, otherwise an `error text would be displayed below`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Show Me My Money!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/cmxformTemplate.css"/>

        <script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" 
        type="text/javascript" src="script/datetimepicker_css.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#Form").validate({
                    rules: {
                        goal: {
                            required: true,
                            number: true
                        },
                        startdate: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        targetdate: {
                            required: true
                        }
                    },
                    goal_description: {
                        required: true
                    }, 
                    messages: {
                        goal: {
                            required: "Please enter numerical value",
                            number: "Please enter a numerical value"
                        },
                        startdate: "Please enter a valid start-date",
                        targetdate: "Please enter a valid target-date",
                        goal_description: "Please enter goal description",
                    },
                    errorLabelContainer: "#ErrorBox", wrapper: "li"

                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Add Goal</h1>
        <fieldset style="width:400;">
            <form  method="post" action="doAddGoal.php" id='Form' enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="id_goal"><b>Goal($): </b></label></td>
                        <td><input id="id_goal" type="text" name="goal" required /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="id_startdate"><b>Start Date: </b></label></td>
                        <td><input id="id_startdate" name="startdate" type="date" size="10"/>
                            <a href="javascript:NewCssCal('id_startdate','ddmmmyyyy')"></a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="id_targetdate"><b>Target Date: </b></label></td>
                        <td><input id="id_targetdate" name="targetdate" type="date" size="10"/>
                            <a href="javascript:NewCssCal('id_targetdate','ddmmmyyyy')"></a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="id_description"><b>Description: </b></label></td>
                        <td><input id="id_description" name="goal_description" type="text" required></td>
                    </tr>

                    <td><label for="id_submit"></label></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>

                </table>
            </form>
            <div><ul style="color:red;" id="ErrorBox"></ul></div>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/end-date-greater-than-start-date-jquery-validation

Comment: You need to convert the user submitted values to instances of the date object on which it is simple to perform the validation you require.