# Validating two date-time local fields by earlier date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, date

I'm currently having a problem. I have two date-time fields a Start Date and an End Date. If i pick a date on the Start date for example October 2,2016 and pick a date on the End date October 1,2016 an alert dialog box should appear that the end date is earlier than the Start Date. How do i validate this via script? Sorry i am still very new to programming.

Comment: Can you please show some code you have tried

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/validate-that-end-date-is-greater-than-start-date-with-jquery

Comment: Checking your link.

Answer (score 0):

try this datetime lib, it has such function
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/
it shoud be something like

```
if (moment(dateBefore).isAfter(dateAfter)) {do somth}
```