# validate start time should not be greater than end time using javascript

Tags: php, jquery, html, formvalidation-plugin

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="labeldate" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Time</label>
    <label for="input_fromdate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">From</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="from_time" name="from_time" placeholder="Pick here">
    </div>
    <label for="input_todate" class="col-sm-1 control-label">To </label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="to_time" name="to_time" value="" placeholder="Pick here">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make sure that `to_time` is always greater than `from_time`.
Lets take `from_time:05:00 PM and to_time:04:00 PM.`
I tried using greater than in jquery but it doesnt work perfectly. I want this to include with my jquery validation code

Comment: please show what you've tried, plus the other jquery code, might help you get the answer quicker!

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/validate-that-end-date-is-greater-than-start-date-with-jquery

Comment: Add jquery code too

Answer (score 1):

I made this simple Javascript working as you requested:

```js
var from_time= "11:00 AM";
var to_time = "10:00 PM";

var from = Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+ from_time);
var to = Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+ to_time);

if (from > to){
   console.log ("From greater than To!");
} else {
   console.log ("To greater than from!")
}
```