# html validate input time minimum dependent on the other

Tags: javascript, html

I will describe the situation from scratch so that there is no clarity in the later stages.

I have Razor/c# code in .cshtml file

it generates table for me

```
  @for (int nr_rows = 0; nr_rows < 31; nr_rows++)
                {
                    var nr_names = nr_rows + 1;              

                        @for (int nr_columns = 0; nr_columns < 18; nr_columns++)
                        {
                            if (nr_columns == 2)
                            {
                                <td id="td01"><input class="InputsForUser" type="time" name="start_@nr_names" id="id_start_@nr_names" /></td>
                            }
                            if (nr_columns == 3)
                            {
                                <td id="td01"><input class="InputsForUser" type="time" name="end_@nr_names" id="id_end_@nr_names" /></td>
                            }

                        }
                }
```

which generates for me html in the browser (interprets in this way)

```html
// ----------------------------------- Day 1
<input class="InputsForUser" type="time" name="start_1" id="id_start_1">
<input class="InputsForUser" type="time" name="end_1" id="id_end"_1>

// ----------------------------------- Day 2
<input class="InputsForUser" type="time" name="start_2" id="id_start_2">
<input class="InputsForUser" type="time" name="end_2" id="id_end_2">

// (...)

// ----------------------------------- Day 31
<input class="InputsForUser" type="time" name="start_31" id="id_start_31">
<input class="InputsForUser" type="time" name="end_31" id="id__end_31">
```

I am trying to make id = end at least equal to id = start, but I have no idea, please help

for example: 
if I enter 12:00 at the start, I cannot enter 11:50 at the end

Answer (score 0):

you can install jquery validate and use

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", 
function(value, element, params) {

    if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
        return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
    }

    return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val()) 
        || (Number(value) > Number($(params).val())); 
},'Must be greater than {0}.');
```

then you can use the rule like this :

```
$("#id_end_1").rules('add', { greaterThan: "#id_start_1" });
```

original answer : [Validate that end date is greater than start date with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/validate-that-end-date-is-greater-than-start-date-with-jquery)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined

Comment: @blackWizard did you install jquery validator in your project 
https://jqueryvalidation.org/ 
you can find in in nuget package manager in your visual studio.
and make sure refer the plugin in your page or your layout page

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex selector for the name (since it start the same), and then change the minimum value of the next element like that:

```js
var startInput = document.querySelectorAll('[name^=start]'); // regex selector for all start time input.
for (var i=0; i < startInput.length; i++) { // iterate them and,
  startInput[i].addEventListener('change', function() { // if start time got some input:
    if (this && this.nextElementSibling) { // check that exist and then
      this.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('min', this.value); // set the minimum value of the end time that follow it
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input class="InputsForUser" type="time" name="start_31" id="id_start_31">
<input class="InputsForUser" type="time" name="end_31" id="id__end_31">
```

Comment: this.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('min', this.value); // set the minimum value of the end time that follow it
  });   ----  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null at HTMLInputElement. <anonymous>