# Validate start date should be less than end date in MM-DD-YYYY using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check end_date should be less than the start date in a form ....

So this is my code

```
start_date = $("#form_data")[0].elements.start_date.value
end_date = $("#form_data")[0].elements.end_date.value

if(start_date < end_date){

}

else{

}
```

I'm getting date as MM-DD-YYYY format

Thiw will not work in the following codition

```
start_date = 12/01/2020
end_date = 01/01/2021
```

I deally December 1 2020 should be less than 1 January 20201

How do I fix this

Comment: Try to convert from String to Date and work with Date.

Comment: Javascript solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript  jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/validate-that-end-date-is-greater-than-start-date-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your date into New Date() in Javascript

- Please follow below mention steps.

start_date = $("#form_data")[0].elements.start_date.value;

end_date = $("#form_data")[0].elements.end_date.value;

var vStartDate = new Date(start_date);
var vEndDate = new Date(end_date);

if(vStartDate < vEndDate ){

}

else{

}